# 'spring.sleuth.integration.websockets.enable=false' doesn't disable tracing the websockets

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I try to disable tracing WebSockets, so I put 'spring.sleuth.integration.websockets.enable=false' to my application.properties, but it seems it does nothing, WebSockets are still being traced.

```
spring.zipkin.baseUrl=https://192.168.99.100:9411/
spring.zipkin.service.name=chatserver
spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1
spring.sleuth.integration.websockets.enable=false
```

This is the heartbeat to keep WebSocket alive, I think it should not be recorded if I disabled it

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the property, you're missing a d at the end [spring.sleuth.integration.websockets.enabled]